# How to speed up the load of a page that has the FACEBOOK php/sdk?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way to speed up the load process of pages that load the Facebook php SDK? I've tried the same page with and without the Facebook php SDK and there is a really BIG difference. Pages without the fb php/sdk loads at least 5 times faster than pages with the SKD.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Without showing a sample page it's hard to tell, but here are some points:

1. Store the graph API results calls in the DB is possible (like the user name, friends...etc)
2. Use the new [Batch Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/batch/) when possible to pack your calls in a single request
3. Use the [real-time api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime/), nothing to say here other than it's really a **crucial** api that is usually ignored by Devs. And here is some info from Facebook:

   > Your application caches data and
   >   receives updates, rather than polling
   >   Facebook’s servers. Caching data and
   >   using this API can improve the
   >   reliability of your application and
   >   decrease its load times.
4. Minimize the use of the Facebook Plugins (Like plugin...etc)
   I've seen a lot of websites (blogs) using the Like plugin on their home pages for posts/articles where 10-20 Like buttons are loaded!
5. Have a read of [Performance](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/performance/) & [Best-Practices](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/best-practices/) documents.

Answer (score 0):

The lagtime you're seeing is the time it takes your server to issue a curl() connection to facebook's servers, not the php sdk in particular.

The time it takes to connect to facebook (the api latency) is generally out of your control so you have a couple options to make your site appear more responsive:

1. Turn the api request into an asynchronus request: Show a loading image on your page until it completes.
2. Turn the api request into a background process: User makes the request which puts all the information you need into one of your tables then have a background process that watches for these requests and completes them like a queue.

Good luck